# How can I prevent CustomExpandablePageView from blocking scrolling in SingleChildScrollView?

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I have two classes. One is just a normal stateful widget that has couple of other widgets. Then the second one is a CustomExpandablePageView that has the feature to expand some widgets set to match the the highest widget in the parent tree.
The CustomExpandablePageView  is set to scroll in horizontal direction and used in the first stateful widget class inside a SingleChildScrollView having its scroll to vertical direction. The CustomExpandablePageView  blocks the scrolling of SingleChildScrollView when the touch is on the hit area of CustomExpandablePageView.

I have tried using a custom widget having the SingleChildScrollView and listener to block the pointer from the CustomExpandablePageView but, make the the widget unresponsive to touch.

HomePage

```
 List<EPView> personalEpViews = [

      EPView(child: Container(width: 200,height: 200,color: Colors.blue,)),

    ];

Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      body: Column(

        children: [

          // topTitle,
          const SizedBox(
            height: 40,
          ),
          const Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
            child: CustomPrimaryAppBar(
                userFullName: "KKKKKKKK",
                userShortLocation: "nxncmxcmx"
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 16,
          ),

          Flexible(
            child: VerticalReportingScrollView(
              controller: scrollController,
              scrollingVertically: (bool value) {
                setState(() {
                  interceptChild = value;
                });
              },
              child: Column(
                children: [

                  // Personal Controls
                  ExpandablePageView(
                      intercept: interceptChild,
                      autoScroll: true,
                      autoScrollDelay: const Duration(seconds: 3),
                      waitDuration: const Duration(seconds: 10),
                      pageController: userPersonalPageController,
                      axisDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                      epChildren: EPChildren(250,personalEpViews)
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 25,
                  ),

                  // Personal Control Indicator
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      SmoothPageIndicator(
                        controller: userPersonalPageController,
                        count: personalEpViews.length,
                        effect: const WormEffect(
                            activeDotColor: Color(getMainGreenColor),
                            dotWidth: 14,
                            dotHeight: 14
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),

                 

                  Container(width: 200,
                        height: 1000,color: Colors.red,),



                             ],
                              ),
                            )
                            ,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),

                  //  Bottom Space
                  const SizedBox(height: 50,)



                ],
              ),
            ),

          )
        ],
      ),
    );
```

ExpandablePageView

```
class ExpandablePageView extends StatefulWidget {
  final EPChildren epChildren;
  final PageController? pageController;
  final Function(int index)? onPageChange;
  final Axis axisDirection;
  final bool intercept;
  final bool autoScroll;
  final Duration autoScrollDelay;
  final Duration autoReturnDelay;
  final Duration waitDuration;

  const ExpandablePageView({
    Key? key,
    required this.epChildren,
    this.pageController,
    required this.axisDirection,
    this.autoReturnDelay = const Duration(seconds: 1),
    this.autoScrollDelay = const Duration(seconds: 2),
    this.autoScroll = false,
    this.waitDuration = const Duration(seconds: 5), this.onPageChange, this.intercept = false,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ExpandablePageView> createState() => _ExpandablePageViewState();
}

class _ExpandablePageViewState extends State<ExpandablePageView>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin, WidgetsBindingObserver {
  late List<double> heights;
  int currentPage = 0;
  var rebuild = false;
  var resize = false;
  var delayedTime = 0;
  Timer? autoScrollTimer;
  Timer? delayTimer;
  bool shouldInterceptTouch = false;


  int resumedTrack = 0;
  double initTextScaleFactor = 0.0;
  double maxHeight = 0.0;
  double get currentHeight => heights[currentPage];

  @override
  void initState() {
    startAutoScroll();


    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
    heights = widget.epChildren.epViews.map((e) => 0.0).toList();
    super.initState();
    widget.pageController?.addListener(() {
      final newPage = widget.pageController?.page?.round() ?? 0;
      if (widget.pageController != null && currentPage != newPage) {
        setState(() => currentPage = newPage);
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    widget.pageController?.dispose();
    autoScrollTimer?.cancel();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    if (state == AppLifecycleState.resumed) {

      // rebuildPageView();

    }
  }

  void rebuildPageView() {
    setState(() {
      rebuild = true;
      if (widget.epChildren.epViews[currentPage].crossDimension == EPView.match && anyWrapDimension()) {
        maxHeight = widget.epChildren.defaultHeight;
        heights[currentPage] = widget.epChildren.defaultHeight;
      } else {
        maxHeight = 0.0;
        heights[currentPage] = 0.0;
      }
      rebuild = false;
    });
  }

  void startAutoScroll() {
    autoScrollTimer = widget.autoScroll
        ? Timer.periodic(widget.autoScrollDelay + widget.autoReturnDelay,
            (timer) {
          if(widget.pageController != null){
            if (currentPage == widget.epChildren.epViews.length - 1) {
              widget.pageController?.animateToPage(0,
                  duration: widget.autoReturnDelay, curve: Curves.ease);
            } else {
              widget.pageController?.nextPage(
                  duration: widget.autoScrollDelay, curve: Curves.ease);
            }
          }
        })
        : null;
  }

  void stopAutoScroll() {
    autoScrollTimer?.cancel();
    autoScrollTimer = null;
    delayTimer?.cancel();
    delayTimer = null;
  }

  void performWait() {
    var checkWait = widget.waitDuration - widget.autoScrollDelay;
    if (checkWait > Duration.zero && delayTimer == null) {
      delayTimer = Timer(checkWait, () {
        startAutoScroll();
      });
    }
  }

  double getMaxHeight(){

    for(var i = 0; i < heights.length; i++){
      if(heights[i] > maxHeight ){
        maxHeight = heights[i];
      }
    }
    return maxHeight;
  }

  Widget getTheChild(int index, EPView epView){
    setState(() => heights[index] = getMaxHeight());
    return epView.child;
  }

  bool anyMatchDimension(){

    bool exist = false;
    for(var i = 0; i < widget.epChildren.epViews.length; i++){
      if(widget.epChildren.epViews[i].crossDimension == EPView.match && widget.axisDirection == Axis.horizontal){
        exist = true;
      }
    }
    return exist;
  }

  bool anyWrapDimension(){
    bool exist = false;
    for(var i = 0; i < widget.epChildren.epViews.length; i++){
      if(widget.epChildren.epViews[i].crossDimension == EPView.wrap || widget.epChildren.epViews[i].crossDimension == null){
        exist = true;
      }
    }
    return exist;
  }

  double getCurrentHeight(){
    // if(widget.epChildren.epViews.isNotEmpty && widget.epChildren.epViews[0].crossDimension != EPView.match){
      return currentHeight;
    // }else{
    //   return widget.epChildren.defaultHeight;
    // }
  }

  double getBeginHeight(){
    // if(widget.epChildren.epViews.isNotEmpty && widget.epChildren.epViews[0].crossDimension != EPView.match){
      return heights[0];
    // }else{
    //   return widget.epChildren.defaultHeight;
    // }
  }

  double getEndHeight(){

    double getHeight = 0;
    if(anyMatchDimension() && heights.isNotEmpty){
      getHeight = getMaxHeight();
    }else{
      getHeight = getCurrentHeight() ;
    }


    if(getHeight != 0){
      return getHeight;
    }else{
      return widget.epChildren.defaultHeight;
    }

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (widget.epChildren.epViews.isNotEmpty) {
      return TweenAnimationBuilder<double>(
        curve: Curves.easeInOutCubic,
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 100),
        tween: Tween<double>(begin:getBeginHeight() ,
            end:resize == false ? anyWrapDimension() ? getEndHeight() : currentHeight : 0.0),
        builder: (context, value, child) => SizedBox(height: value, child: child),
        child: GestureDetector(
          onVerticalDragDown: (k) {
            // Scrolling is vertical on the children stopping auto scroll
            if (widget.axisDirection == Axis.vertical) {
              stopAutoScroll();
            }
          },

          onVerticalDragCancel: () {
            // Scrolling in vertical on the children stopped start auto scroll
            if (widget.axisDirection == Axis.vertical) {
              performWait();
            }
          },
          onHorizontalDragDown: (a) {
            // Scrolling is horizontal on the children stopping auto scroll
            if (widget.axisDirection == Axis.horizontal) {
              stopAutoScroll();
            }
          },
          onHorizontalDragCancel: () {
            // Scrolling in horizontal on the children stopped start auto scroll
            if (widget.axisDirection == Axis.horizontal) {
              performWait();
            }
          },
          child: IgnorePointer(
            ignoring: widget.intercept,
            child: PageView(
              onPageChanged: (index){
                if(widget.onPageChange != null){
                  widget.onPageChange!(index);
                }
              },
              scrollDirection: widget.axisDirection,
              controller: widget.pageController,
              children: rebuild == false
              // Rebuild is false
                  ? _sizeReportingChildren
                  .asMap() //
                  .map((index, child) => MapEntry(index, child))
                  .values
                  .toList()
              // Rebuild is true
                  : [],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    } else {
      return const SizedBox();
    }
  }

  List<Widget> get _sizeReportingChildren => widget.epChildren
      .epViews.asMap() //
      .map(
        (index, epView) => MapEntry(
      index,
      // Check the views cross dimension
      epView.crossDimension == EPView.match && index != 0
      // child is set to match the parent
          ? Column(children: [
        Expanded(
            child: Container(child: getTheChild(index, epView)
            )
          )
         ])
          : OverflowBox(
        //needed, so that parent won't impose its constraints on the children, thus skewing the measurement results.
        minHeight: 0,
        maxHeight: double.infinity,
        alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
        child: SizeReportingWidget(
          onSizeChange: (size) {

            setState(() {
              // epView.crossDimension != EPView.match &&
              if(anyWrapDimension()){
                if(size.height < maxHeight){
                  resize = true;
                  maxHeight = 0.0;
                  heights[currentPage] = 0.0;
                  resize = false;
                }
                heights[index] = size.height;

              }else{

                if(index <= 0){
                  heights[index] = size.height;
                }

              }
            });
          },
          child: Align(child: epView.child),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  )
      .values
      .toList();
}

class EPChildren{
  final double defaultHeight;
  final List<EPView> epViews;
  EPChildren(this.defaultHeight, this.epViews);
}

class EPView {
  final String? crossDimension;
  final Widget child;

  EPView({this.crossDimension, required this.child});
  static const wrap = "-0.0W";
  static const match = "0.0M";

}
```

VerticalReportingScrollView

```
class VerticalReportingScrollView extends StatefulWidget {
  final ScrollController controller;
  final ValueChanged<bool> scrollingVertically;
  final Widget child;
  const VerticalReportingScrollView({Key? key, required this.controller, required this.scrollingVertically, required this.child}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<VerticalReportingScrollView> createState() => _VerticalReportingScrollViewState();
}

class _VerticalReportingScrollViewState extends State<VerticalReportingScrollView> {
  var vertical = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();


      widget.controller.addListener(() {

        if (widget.controller.position.userScrollDirection ==
            ScrollDirection.forward || widget.controller.position.userScrollDirection ==
            ScrollDirection.reverse) {

          setState(() {
            if(!vertical){
              vertical = true;
              widget.scrollingVertically(vertical);
            }
          });
        }


      });



  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    widget.controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
  // gestures: {
  //   AllowMultipleGestureRecognizer:
  //   GestureRecognizerFactoryWithHandlers<AllowMultipleGestureRecognizer>(
  //         () => AllowMultipleGestureRecognizer(),
  //         (AllowMultipleGestureRecognizer instance) {},
  //   ),
  // },
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Listener(
      onPointerUp: (PointerUpEvent pointerUpEvent ){
        if(vertical){
          setState(() {
            vertical = false;
            widget.scrollingVertically(vertical);
          });
        }
      },
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        controller: widget.controller,
        child: widget.child,
      ),
    );
  }
}

// class AllowMultipleGestureRecognizer extends GestureRecognizer {
//   @override
//   void addPointer(PointerEvent event) {
//     // Check the pointer event here before dispatching it to the widget
//     // showToastMobile(
//     //     msg: '$event');
//     // super.addPointer(event);
//   }
//
//   @override
//   String get debugDescription => 'AllowMultipleGestureRecognizer';
//
//   @override
//   void didStopTrackingLastPointer(int pointer) {}
//
//   @override
//   void dispose() {}
//
//   @override
//   void handleEvent(PointerEvent event) {}
//
//   @override
//   void rejectGesture(int pointer) {}
//
//   @override
//   void acceptGesture(int pointer) {
//   }
// }
```

Please help me check for what widget i could use cause i already tried nested which could normally control the touching that are vertical to horizontal

Answer (score 0):

I figured it was because i was listening to vertical drag in the CustomExpandablePageView so removing it solved my problem.